# android: how to use an scrolling layout into our recyclerView layout?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview which each rows of it ,have an scrolling layout.
the scrolling layout is filled with text views in linear layout , which the are received from server

[image: app screenshot]

> but the scrollview in recycler layout is not scrolling (recycler is
>   scrolling fine).

anyone knows what is the problem ?!

my recycler layout code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="15dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_payer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/payer"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/payer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/txt_payer"
        android:text="@string/payer"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cost"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:text="@string/cost_t"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_cost"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/cost"
        android:text="@string/cost_t"
        android:textColor="#000000" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txt_payer"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/cost_for_me"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:text="@string/cost_for_me"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_cost_for_me"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:text="@string/cost_for_me"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/calender"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scroll_list"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/partner_list"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" />
            </ScrollView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_partners"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:text="@string/partners"
                android:textColor="#000000" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/linear2"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

the problem should be here in this tag :

```
   <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/partner_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
```

> text views received from server are added dynamically to this layout.

java code :

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
final ArrayList<RecyclerViewDataReport> items = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<>();
name.add("sajad");
name.add("sajad");
name.add("sajad");
name.add("sajad");
name.add("sajad");
name.add("sajad");
name.add("sajad");
name.add("sajad");
name.add("sajad");
name.add("sajad");
name.add("sajad");

for (int i=0 ; i<10 ; i++){
    RecyclerViewDataReport temp = new RecyclerViewDataReport("sajad" , "111111", "99999" , "4444" , name);
    items.add(temp);
}

// 2. set layoutManger
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
// 3. create an adapter
mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapterReport(items, getActivity());
// 4. set adapter
recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
// 5. set item animator to DefaultAnimator
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use setNestedScrollingEnabled method

```
 recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the touch event to do this effectively:

```
//do this after seting adapter in recycler

    parent.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            findViewById(R.id.inner_scroll).getParent()
                    .requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
            return false;
        }
    });

//do this in bind view holder

    innerScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            return false;
        }
    });
```